# Count single instance in subset of data

Tags: business-objects

Good morning all.  I am working in Business Objects and am building essentially a history table and am having an issue summarizing it.  A sample of Data is below.

```
Region  Ref#  Level  
East     1     0  
East     1     1  
East     1     2  
East     2     0  
West     3     0  
West     3     1
```

What I want the output to be is below (Crosstable):

```
Level   0   1   2  
East    1   -   1  
West    -   1   -
```

Comment: Can you explain how the data is being summarized?

Comment: There is 1 count of a Ref# in the east that is at level 2.  There is 1 count of a Ref# in the east that is at level 0.  There is 1 count of a Ref# in the west at level 1.

Comment: Aren't there 2 Ref#s in the East at Level 0? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve rather than just transform this table into that one?

Comment: Yes, there are two...however, since Ref#1 went through Level 0, I just want to see what has stopped at Level 2.  Basically I want to show what level each Ref# is at currently, not what level they have been through if that makes more sense.